# Entity Framework DateTime Functions

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to filter by date based on two datetimes. `MinTime` and `MaxTime` are both nullable DateTimes in SQL, I want to filter based on these, but I'm getting an error:

`This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities`

```
public static IEnumerable<ExclusionRule> GetExclusionRules(AppointmentTypes? apptType, string resourceName, TimeSpan? minTime, TimeSpan? maxTime, DayOfWeek? day) {
    using (var db = new BusinessObjectContainer()) {
        db.ExclusionRules.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
        var items = db.ExclusionRules;
        int intDay = day.HasValue ? (int) day.Value : -1,
            intApptType = apptType.HasValue ? (int)apptType.Value : -1;
        var filteredApptType = apptType.HasValue ? items.Where(i => !i.t_AppointmentType.HasValue|| i.t_AppointmentType == intApptType) : items;
        var filteredResource = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resourceName) ? filteredApptType : filteredApptType.Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.ResourceName) && resourceName.ToLower().Equals(i.ResourceName.ToLower()));

        IEnumerable<ExclusionRule> filteredMinDate;
        if (minTime.HasValue) {
            filteredMinDate = filteredResource.Where(i => (!i.MinTime.HasValue) || (EntityFunctions.CreateTime(i.MinTime.Value.Hour, i.MinTime.Value.Minute, 0) >= minTime.Value));
        } else {
            filteredMinDate = filteredResource;
        }

        IEnumerable<ExclusionRule> filteredMaxDate;
        if (maxTime.HasValue) {
            // this throws the exception
            filteredMaxDate = filteredMinDate.Where(i => (!i.MaxTime.HasValue) || EntityFunctions.CreateTime(i.MaxTime.Value.Hour, i.MaxTime.Value.Minute, 0) <= maxTime.Value);
        } else {
            filteredMaxDate = filteredMinDate;
        }
        var filteredWeekDay= day.HasValue ? filteredMaxDate.Where(i => !i.t_DayOfWeek.HasValue|| i.t_DayOfWeek == intDay) : filteredMaxDate;
        return filteredWeekDay.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `EntityFunctions`* in a linq statement on an `IEnumerable<ExclusionRule>`. But you can only use it on an IQueryable that has an Entity Framework query provider. So you should start with `IQueryable<ExclusionRule>` (from EF) or just create `DateTime`s in the regular.Net way.

<sup>*[DbFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.aspx) as of Entity Framework 6.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

MinTime.Value.Hour etc. might have to be executed in a Query and it seems to me that you are excecuting them in .Net memory. That's why you get the error.

LINQ to entities:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities`

`EntityFunctions` is applicable is LINQ to Entities queries only.

The `EntityFunctions` class contains methods that expose canonical functions to use in LINQ to Entities queries. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456873.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by calling `.ToList()` before the DateTime filtering. This pulls everything into .NET so the querying can be done there.

As there are a relatively small number of items in my database this wasn't a problem.